# Linking issues with leptonica and libpng

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, csh

Working through an install of tesseract without sudo permissions and without a standard bevy of prebuilt libraries. The installation I've got to go through as far as I know follows the path of zlib -> libpng -> leptonica -> tesseract.

Each installation by itself is successful, the main issues I'm running into is that for some reason leptonica cannot find the relevant libpng installation. Process below:

```
zlib:
 ./configure --prefix={dir}/local
 make
 make check
 make install

libpng:
 ./configure --prefix={dir}/local
 make
 make check
 make install
```

To confirm I check my installs and see that libpng appears to be installed:

```
JNG* PNG       rw-   JPEG Network Graphics
     MNG* PNG       rw+   Multiple-image Network Graphics (libpng 1.5.13)
     PNG* PNG       rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.5.13)
          See http://www.libpng.org/ for details about the PNG format.
   PNG24* PNG       rw-   opaque 24-bit RGB (zlib 1.2.7,1.2.11)
   PNG32* PNG       rw-   opaque or transparent 32-bit RGBA
    PNG8* PNG       rw-   8-bit indexed with optional binary transparency
```

The issue though is that the `libpng` library referenced above is not the version I'm installing. For `zlib` I've installed `1.2.11`, so that seems to be working. For `libpng` I'm installing `1.6.35`, so while the `make check` and `make install` commands seem to be working, it's not being recognized. I've tried more manual linking. (env is `csh` and believe me I'd change it if I could.)

```
setenv PATH $PATH\:{dir}/local/bin
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH {dir}/local/lib
setenv LD_RUN_PATH {dir}/local/lib/
```

However, still not seeing the correct version of `libpng` show up.

Shows up in `leptonica` when I run `./configure --prefix={dir}/local`:

```
checking for ZLIB... yes
checking for LIBPNG... no
```

So outside of versions, it's not finding any `libpng` library. Installing `leptonica 1.74.4`.

I'm very used to just installing everything under `sudo` so this is kind of new territory to me, and I'm unfamiliar with `csh` so part of me worried that I've mucked up my environment settings somehow. Any clue what's going on and how I can get `leptonica` to find `libpng`?

Comment: Has your distribution installed a different version?

Comment: @novice Even that would be fine, it's just not linking at all

Comment: Do you have pkg-config installed?